# How to set up HTTPS on golang web server?

Tags: go, https

I'm reading https://www.kaihag.com/https-and-go/ and bought an SSL certificate from Comodo which they emailed me a `.zip` file. All of the files I have so far look like this

```
csr.pem
private-key.pem
website.com.crt
website.com.ca-bundle
website.com.zip
```

The above website wants me to concatenate 3 `.pem` files which I don't have. Incidentally what is the reason the `.pem` files need to concatenated? Using the above files which haven't been modified, how can https be set up on a golang webserver?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS

```
http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
log.Printf("About to listen on 10443. Go to https://127.0.0.1:10443/")
err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":10443", "full-cert.crt", "private-key.key", nil)
log.Fatal(err)
```

For Go you need one certificate file (containing one or more certs, starting with yours) and one private key file (containing one private key).

This isn't really a go question, but the intermediate certs are required because computers only store root certs. By concatenating them you put them all in one file so the browser gets all certs - this is a required step otherwise your server will fail on certain devices. Your cert provider will provide instructions for doing this.

https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=18923

To combine the certs you can just use cat (making sure they have a line feed at the end of the file first), something like:

```
cat example.com.ca-crt example.com.ca-bundle > example.com.crt
```

Comment: I'm not sure why that cat cmd doesn't work on me, but I merged them manually with text editor it works well now. Thank you!

Comment: The most common reason for cat not working would be the lack of a new line at the end of the first file).

Answer (score 6):

You need `http.ListenAndServeTLS`

```
package main

import (
    // "fmt"
    // "io"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("This is an example server.\n"))
    // fmt.Fprintf(w, "This is an example server.\n")
    // io.WriteString(w, "This is an example server.\n")
}

func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/hello", HelloServer)
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "server.crt", "server.key", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Here’s a snippet: https://gist.github.com/denji/12b3a568f092ab951456

Comment: Yes but IIRC doesn't the server.crt have to be created by concatenating files together? I may be remembering wrong though

Comment: If I got right these are certificates of issuer. Including such certificates and creating bundle is good because browsers (Firefox of previous versions) did not accept your correct certificate if didn’t have access to a full chain. You may start with Chrome browser to debug all the things. Then join all the certificates to a bundle and deploy with it

Answer (score 1):

Here is my finding and I would like to share because it took me a few hours as all available installation guides were for Nginx and Apache HTTP configurations, not for the Golang Web Server.

Environments:

- SSL certificate from Comodo / Sectigo
- Gin-gonic as middleware

Issue:

- It was working fine on Chrome/Firefox on Mac but was giving me a CORS error on Windows Firefox. Later, it was found that it was not really a CORS related matter, and I diagnosed my ubuntu server of the SSL validity by using https://www.digicert.com/help. The result was, "The certificate is not signed by a trusted authority (checking against Mozilla's root store)".

Solution:

The solution is to concatenate the following certificates by using a text editor and name it as you'd like. I saved it as "my_domain.txt".

- my_domain.ca-bundle (which includes one root and two intermediate certs)
- my_domain.crt (the main cert for my domain)

Then run it like this,

```
router.RunTLS(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), "../my_domain.txt", "../my_private_key.txt")
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The library https://github.com/adrianosela/sslmgr abstracts away the whole concept of keys and certificates. All you need is for the server to be reachable by the hostname (i.e. your DNS must point yourdomain.com to your-public-ip). You can even disable SSL for local development as follows:

```
ss, err := sslmgr.NewServer(sslmgr.ServerConfig{
    Hostnames: []string{os.Getenv("yourdomain.com")},
    Handler:   h,
    ServeSSLFunc: func() bool {
        return strings.ToLower(os.Getenv("PROD")) == "true"
    },
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
ss.ListenAndServe()
```

Answer (score -1):

> IF You Using Go language gin library then use this replace `r.run`

Here

1. `server.pem` = Your SSL intermediate Root CA Certificate.
2. `server.key` = Your SSL Key File. `:8080` = Your Listen port.

> `r.RunTLS(":8080", "./testdata/server.pem", "./testdata/server.key")`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30537438)