# How to set up an https server with a self-signed certificate in golang

Tags: go, ssl, https

I'm trying to set up an https server (`http.ListenAndServeTLS()`) with a self-signed certificate to listen for a webhook updates from a service (I'm sure this service has no problem working with such certificates), but it fails and constantly prints

```
<date> <time> http: TLS handshake error from <IP>: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

I've looked for solutions and tried several (setting `InsecureSkipVerify` to true in `TLSConfig`, adding my certificate to the `Certificates` field of the config or signing another certificate with self-signed one and appending the latter to the `RootCAs`), but nothing solves the issue (the last solution unsurprisingly changes the error to `unknown certificate authority`).

As I've mentioned, I'm pretty sure the problem isn't related to the service I'm trying to listen to, so there must be something really simple that I'm missing about setting up a server in Go. My code looks something like this:

```
    rootCAs, _ := x509.SystemCertPool()
    if rootCAs == nil {
        rootCAs = x509.NewCertPool()
    }
    certs, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(CA_PATH)
    _ = rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(certs);

    server := http.Server{
        Addr: "",
        Handler: nil,
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
            Certificates: []tls.Certificate{ my_cert },
            RootCAs: rootCAs,
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(server.ListenAnsServeTLS(PEM_PATH, KEY_PATH))
```

Comment: look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992030/how-to-set-up-https-on-golang-web-server), it may help.

Comment: @HosseinNazari I've seen it, but it seems to not be the case as a bought (signed by a CA) certificate is used there.

Comment: What is the result of AppendCertsFromPEM? Maybe it failed?

Comment: @BurakSerdar in my actual code (which is too much of a mess to include in a question) I check for all return values like errors or boolean result of AppendCertsFromPEM. The function (as well as ReadFile above it) doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: In the log you see "remote error". This means that it is the other end that sends a TLS alert, so it is the other end (the HTTPS client) that doesn't accept the certificate. InsecureSkipVerify is only for clients, but you are writing a server. You need to configure the HTTPS client (webhook service) to accept your certificate.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in [RFC2246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246), the handshake protocol establishes a TLS session and negotiates the security permissions between the client and the server. By default, your machine already trusts a set of certificates from many Certificate Authorities like: [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy), [IdenTrust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IdenTrust), [DigiCert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiCert), etc. When you are the Certificate Authority (self-signed certificate way), you need to provide the certificate to the client, and the client needs to trust that certificate. So what you need to do is:

after openssl tool installation, run the command below:

```
openssl req -new -subj "/C=US/ST=Utah/CN=localhost" -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.csr
```

that command generates a `localhost.key` file which is the private key and `localhost.csr` which is the certificate signing request (CSR) that contains the public key. The `CN` passed in `-subj` is the most important field because some browsers like chrome require that information. `CN` means Common Name and it is the domain name that you would like to have SSL secured. Then, you need to generate the certificate file:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in localhost.csr -signkey localhost.key -out localhost.crt
```

The `localhost.crt` file is generated by the command above and it's the self-signed certificate signed by your own `localhost.key` private key. The `x509` flag states the standard format of an SSL/TLS certificate which is `X.509`.

After that you need to use the cert and key to serve the `https` self signed server:

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS("8081", "localhost.crt","localhost.key", router))
```

In the client side, is very important that it trusts the server certificate, instead of using curl's `-k` parameter, that parameter will ignore TLS protocol. If you're using a linux OS, install the `ca-certificates` package and then copy the `localhost.crt` to `ca-certificates` folder:

```
cp localhost.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localhost.crt
```

finally trust that certificate with the command below:

```
update-ca-certificates
```

If you're using a different OS than linux you can follow one of these steps: [Mac Os](https://tosbourn.com/getting-os-x-to-trust-self-signed-ssl-certificates/), [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/370217/trust-ssl-certificate-to-local-system-account), [Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list). You'll find a complete example in this [github repo](https://github.com/luizhlelis/go-lang-https-self-signed).

Answer (score 6):

Create a directory golangssl and enter it

```
mkdir golangssl
cd golangssl
```

Generate a selfsigned key and cert (install openssl if not yet installed)

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 -out server.key
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -key server.key -out server.crt -days 3650
```

Create a file server.go with the following content

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func SecureServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("Secure Hello World.\n"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/secure", SecureServer)
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "server.crt", "server.key", nil)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
 }
```

Run the server (needs root rights, because of binding of port 443)

```
sudo go run server.go
```

Execute a request (`-k` for ignoring the self signed certificate)

```
 curl -k https://localhost/secure
```

Output should be

```
 Secure Hello World.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem, same output ("bad certificate"). Is the name and location of golangssl directory important?

Comment: No, the location should't make a difference. Who is issuing the bad certificate? The client or the server?